# Place screenshots on Desktop on Display 2

Tags: macos, display, screen-capture

How can I do to tell the system that every time that takes an screenshot place it on Desktop, but on Second Monitor?

It only must be placed on Display 1 when Display 2 won't be available.

Answer (score 1):

I could never find a way to set this with a machine preference.  I ended up just creating a folder on my second monitor name **"ScreenShots"** and setting the default location for screenshots to that folder.  They will then save to that desktop and into that folder.

**Change the default location to new folder on external monitor:**

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Desktop/ScreenShots/
```

**Restart the SystemUIServer to make it take affect:**

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

Comment: Sorry mate, I have a completely clean desktop and I don't want to create a folder for it.